# Angularjs ng-repeat hide/show

Tags: angularjs

I have a table where I am using ng-repeat to replicate a series of 4 checkboxes. When the user selects one of the "OAuth2" check boxes in subsequent table rows I need to show a div which is outside the table. I have tried using ng-model="OAuth2" and then using  ng-show="OAuth2" for the div outside of the table but it does not work.  (It works fine if the div is inside the table),

```
//Here's the HTML
<table class="table table-striped" width="100%" border="0">
        <thead align="center">
          <tr align="center">
            <th width="15%">Environment</th>
            <th width="16%">Datacenter 1</th>
            <th width="16%">Datacenter 2</th>
            <th colspan="2">Auth Protocol</th>
            <th colspan="2">socketTimeout</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="route in routes">
            <td><select class="form-control" ng-model="route.environ" >
                <option>E2E</option>
                <option>PERF</option>
                <option>PROD</option>
                <option>STAGE</option>
                <option>PDS</option>
                <option>QAL</option>
              </select></td>
            <td><select ng-model="myDataCenter1">
                <option ng-repeat="datacenter1 in datacenter1s" value="{{datacenter1.value}}" ng-selected="datacenter1.value == myDataCenter1">{{datacenter1.name}}</option>
              </select></td>
            <td><select ng-model="myDataCenter2">
                <option ng-repeat="datacenter2 in datacenter2s" value="{{datacenter2.value}}" ng-selected="datacenter2.value == myDataCenter2">{{datacenter2.name}}</option>
              </select></td>
            <td width="16%"><div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <small> PrivateAuth</small></label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <small> BrowserAuth</small></label>
              </div></td>
            <td width="12%"><div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <small> SimpleAuth</small></label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="OAuth2">
                  <small> OAuth2</small></label>
              </div></td>
            <td width="10%"><input class="form-control" type="text" value="5"/></td>
            <td width="13%">secs</td>
            <td width="2%"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="removeRoute(route)">X</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="8" align="right"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="addRoute()">+ ADD MORE</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div ng-show="OAuth2">Show this content</div>



     //Here's the JavaScript
     /* ROUTES -  Datacenter section to populate table and add remove routes */
    $scope.routes = [
        {environ:'E2E', data1:'',data2:'',auth:'',socket:''},
        {environ:'PERF', data1:'',data2:'',auth:'',socket:''},
        {environ:'PROD', data1:'',data2:'',auth:'',socket:''}
    ];

    $scope.addRoute = function() {
        this.routes.push({environ:'', data1:'',data2:'',auth:'',socket:''});
    };

    $scope.removeRoute = function(routeToRemove) {
        var index = this.routes.indexOf(routeToRemove);
        this.routes.splice(index, 1);
    };
```

Comment: sample code would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope.  When you set the value `checked`, that is only present on the child scope and you can't see it outside.  Create an object in your parent scope called `data` or something and use `data.checked` as your value.  The data object will be inherited by the child scope and you can use the value in the parent.

If you just use `checked` on the parent scope it will inherit, but as soon as you set the value in the child scope it breaks the inheritance [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/hn8U3/)

Comment: scope inheritance in depth: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes